# Laravel RESTful Controller - Params Before Action Name

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have `UsersController` which is RESTful controller, there are some functions within it.

inside `UsersController.php`:

```
function postOutletVisit($id){
   // some code
}
```

inside `routes.php` :

```
Route::controller('users', 'UsersController');
```

with this route I can access `postOutletVisit` action like this:

`[POST] mydomain.com/users/outlet-visit/{id}`

But I'm wondering if it's possible to convert that link to:

`[POST] mydomain.com/users/{id}/outlet-visit`

I know that I can do this by defining routes for every action like:

`Route::post('users/{id}/outlet-visit', 'UsersController@outletVisit')`

But this is not suitable for me because there are plenty of actions inside UsersConroller and I will loose the greate naming convenient for actions (first part of action name determines the method used in it, instead of defining the methods separately in `routes.php` file)

Comment: outlet-visit is a database model which is related to the user whose id is {id}, I'll consider creating a separate controller for it.
I know I have much choices but I was wondering if changing the default position for the parameters is possible.

Comment: Actually after your first comment I get your hint, I achieved the behavior I want by creating separate controller for `OutletVisit`, registered it in my route like this `Route::controller('users/{id}/visits', 'OutletVisitController');`, I am pretty new for this routes ability recently I came from `CodeIgniter` and I found `Laravel` better in every field.

Comment: @arthurfl I suggest you to add your comments as an answer to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlet Visit is a specific resource, so it doesn't belong in your UserController and should have its own controller.

```
class OutletController extends BaseController
{
    public function postStore($userId)           // Controller for storing Outlet Visits
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then you define your routes for OutletController, specifying that you need to attach it to a specific user :

```
Route::controller('users/{id}/outlet', 'OutletController');
```

If needed you can add more actions for this Controller, such as listing, forms for adding / editing, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I think you mean to use `Route::resource('users', 'UsersController')`.

Secondly, of course you can. Just overload the other route method underneath:

```
// This defines the predefined Laravel routing
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController')

Route::post('users/{id}/outlet-visit', 'UsersController@outletVisit');
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I meant every thing in my post, I can and I know how to do what you mentioned (it's there in my post!), but I'm looking for something more efficient.

Comment: OH sorry, I misread you. In that case, I don't think you really have much of a choice. The default `Route::resource` is made to follow the RESTful convention. If you want to define your own, you have to use the provided methods (such as `Route::get`). That is why they exist.

Answer (score 0):

There are no ways to change the urls created by the method `Route::controller` unless you extend it.